# Cypress does not show autocomplete intellisense in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, npm, cypress

I am using Cypress version 12.17.1 with VS Code in Windows 10.

I am trying to write cypress code in Visual Studio Code, but the problem I am facing is that the cypress commands starting with `cy` are not suggested as auto-complete (intellisense). For eample, in the below image, the suggestions in `should('')` only show when I require the cypress.

[image: cypress-intellisense-vscode]

Above suggestions only work if I explicitly import the cypress as:

```
const cypress = require("cypress")
```

But if I include the above statements in my cypress test file e.g. e2e/test.cy.js, then I get the error [Cypress: process is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71868966/cypress-process-is-not-defined) when I try to run my tests.
So basically every time I want to run my tests, I have to delete this line and then run the tests.
Is there a way to avoid the above error, or get the cypress suggestions to work without requiring the cypress package?

Comment: Did you read the docs? E.g. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/ide-integration#Triple-slash-directives

Comment: you import it as `cypress` but want to refer to it as `cy`?

Answer (score 2):

You can also add a `jsconfig.json` to the project root. I use

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["cypress", "./cypress/support/index.d.ts"]
  }
}
```

where the entry for `"cypress"` is the types defined by Cypress, and the entry for `"./cypress/support/index.d.ts"` is for custom commands defined in the project.

Or Cypress mentions a "dummy" `tsconfig.json` here [cypress-example-todomvc](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-todomvc#cypress-intellisense)

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "types": [
      "cypress"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "cypress/**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue to resolve by adding the following line at the top to enable intellisense for Cypress JS in VS Code:

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />
```

This answer helped me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52440156/7673215